# How to capture webpage node screenshot with translucency?

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools, webpage-screenshot

How to capture webpage node screenshot with translucency?

For example, capture the text rendering from a specific div with transparent background.

"Node screenshot" feature of Chrome/Firefox devtools has two problems:

1. (Minor) They capture the region of the node, but including contents of other nodes.
2. (Major) I don't know how, or if it is possible to erase background and capture as a transparent background.